# Calculate time passed since $STARDATE and current date

Tags: bash

I want to establish the amount of time that has passed since 24th February 2008 - time 17:28 UTC

The output would be something like:

Its been x years x months x days x hours x minute x seconds since Tottenham Won a Trophy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python:

```
python -c "from datetime import datetime as d; print(d.today() - d(2008, 2, 24, 17, 28, 0))"
```

Or you have to build something like:

```
starttime=$(date -d "2008-02-24 17:28 UTC" +%s)
current=$(date +%s)

timediff=$((current - starttime))
echo $timediff
days=$((timediff/86400))
hours=$((timediff%86400/3600))
min=$((timediff%3600/60))
sec=$((timediff%60))
echo "$days days $hours hours $min minutes $sec seconds since start"
```

Years and month would be more difficult